# update sql after form submit

Tags: php, sql, forms

Okay guys, I'm newbie here but 
1. I want to UPDATE my sql after I input number on the text box. it echos correctly but doesn't change the DB.
2. I want to remove the first submit button and make it onchange event.

I'm really confused here. Thanks guys! This work is almost done. been doing it for a long time already. I'm still learning php, please bear wit me. thanks

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select * from english");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form name='form' method = POST>";
echo "<select name = 'Students'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$LRN = $row['LRN'];
$Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
$First = $row['First_Name'];
echo '<option value="'.$LRN.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';

}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Show'>";


if (isset($_POST['Students'])) {
$lrn = $_POST['Students'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Level, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, FINAL FROM english WHERE LRN = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $lrn);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($last, $first, $level, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $final);
$stmt->fetch();
   echo "<table><tr><th>LRN</th><th>Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th><th>Q4</th><th>Final</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>$lrn</td><td>$last, $first</td><td>$level</td><td>$q1</td><td>$q2</td><td>$q3</td><td>$q4</td><td>$final</td></tr></table>";
}



///////////EDIT DATA
echo "Edit Data: ";
echo "<select name = 'Edit'>";

echo '<option value=Q1>Q1</option>';
echo '<option value=Q2>Q2</option>';
echo '<option value=Q3>Q3</option>';
echo '<option value=Q4>Q4</option>';
echo '<option value=FINAL>FINAL</option>';
echo '<input type="number" name="editdata">';
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2' value='Edit Now'>";


if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {
$upd = $_POST['Edit'];
$txt = $_POST['editdata'];
$now = "UPDATE english SET $upd=$txt WHERE LRN=$lrn";
$result2 = $conn->query($now);
echo $now;
    }



echo "</form>";



echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: It is open to SQL injections but that probably isn't the testing cause. Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to determine the error.

Comment: my problem isn't the connection to DB tho. I think it's my php code.

Comment: Since `it doesn't change the DB` you should look at what happens when you execute the query. That error function is for queries, not the connection. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php is for connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your input in quotes or else SQL thinks you're trying to reference columns instead of strings.

`$now = "UPDATE english SET $upd=\"$txt\" WHERE LRN=\"$lrn\"";`

or if you prefer single quotes to avoid escaping w backslash then this should work the same:

`$now = "UPDATE english SET $upd='$txt' WHERE LRN='$lrn'";`

Also, this is not best practice, as mentioned by chris85 you are subject to injection attacks, if you want best practice then you want to use this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: The values the OP has shown would work in the query unquoted (although open to injections).  `$txt` despite the name is actually a number as is `$lrn` and `$upd` is a column (could backtick it but alphanumerical should be fine).

Comment: good point - you may be right, but depending on the mysql schema, i may be right if the LRN column is defined as string and not number.

Comment: The column type won't matter. The query fails because of syntax. You can try to set an integer column to a string, if composed right it will insert as `0`.

Comment: so even I add backlash or just the " ", still doesn't update DB.

Comment: what happens if you take the query output by your line: `echo $now;` and copy and paste it into mysql command line?